# Target each '*' inside brackets

Tags: php, regex

I was wondering is it possible to target each instance of a charcter inside brakets.

For example I want to target each '*' symbol here:

> [ Lorem ipsum *dolor sit *amet, consectetur *adipisicing elit ]

but I don't want to target it if it is outside of the brakets

> Lorem ipsum *dolor sit *amet, consectetur *adipisicing elit

So I started from zero: `\*/g` target all instances of the `*`.
If i do this: `\[.+?(\*).+\]` I can get the last instance of it, but is there a way to target them all ? Or I have to extract each sentence in brakets and target them separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this, assuming that you are sure that the brackets are balanced and that you don't have nested brackets:

```
\*(?=[^[]*\])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bH4mE3)

If you have nesting and balanced brackets and want to replace all the asterisks, then some recursion will be required:

```
\*(?=(?:[^][]|(\[(?:[^][]|(?1))*\]))*\])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tP7aA2)

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
/(?!=\[.*)\*(?=.*\])/g
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/yX9lZ8

Comment: You sir are a live savior. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not a sir, I'm just 14, don't call me sir. By the way welcome!